# How to draw a continuous line with mouse on JavaFX canvas?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

The code below results in a JavaFX Canvas that can be drawn on with the mouse pointer but skips some points, i.e., leaves gaps if one tries to draw a continuous line. The gapping intensifies as pointer speed increases.

**What causes this behaviour and what can be done to achieve a well-connected line?** *(N.B., I'm looking for an answer that explicitly toggles each single pixel the pointer passes over to black, not operations such as smoothing or connecting dots, etc.)*

```
public class DrawingSample extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 300);
        flowPane.getChildren().add(canvas);
        GraphicsContext graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        graphicsContext.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        graphicsContext.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged((event) -> {
            graphicsContext.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            graphicsContext.fillRect(event.getX(), event.getY(), 1, 1);
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(flowPane));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(DrawingSample.class);
    }
}
```

The following figure demonstrates three lines drawn from left to right at increasing speeds as we go down.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code from [here](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/04/free-draw-on-javafx-canvas.html).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @web http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/
 */
public class JavaFX_DrawOnCanvas extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
        final GraphicsContext graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        initDraw(graphicsContext);

        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, 
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                graphicsContext.beginPath();
                graphicsContext.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                graphicsContext.stroke();
            }
        });

        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                graphicsContext.stroke();
            }
        });

        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void initDraw(GraphicsContext gc){
        double canvasWidth = gc.getCanvas().getWidth();
        double canvasHeight = gc.getCanvas().getHeight();

        gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setLineWidth(5);

        gc.fill();
        gc.strokeRect(
                0,              //x of the upper left corner
                0,              //y of the upper left corner
                canvasWidth,    //width of the rectangle
                canvasHeight);  //height of the rectangle

        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        gc.setLineWidth(1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Cant we just use the [Line](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Line.html) directly and just change the endX() and endY() on mouse drag?

Comment: I doubt it. Line draws a straight line.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, I thought OP was asking for a straight line :)

Answer (score 6):

Sorry about previous message, should have asked a question in a new thread, right?

Here's a solution that works better, not creating the strange lines like in the scribbletest above.

```
canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, 
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        graphicsContext.beginPath();
        graphicsContext.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        graphicsContext.stroke();

    }
});

canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        graphicsContext.stroke();
        graphicsContext.closePath();
        graphicsContext.beginPath();
        graphicsContext.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    }
});

canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        graphicsContext.stroke();
        graphicsContext.closePath();
    }
});
```

Comment: The other AnswerPost `stoke()` too many times on the same path -- which is unable to draw a line with **opacity**. \
This AnswerPost `beginPath()` & `closePath()` many times, but solves the problem above.