# JavaFX MouseMove while button is pressed on a canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, javafx

I am writing a JavaFX application and I added a `Canvas` to a window.

Now when I register events for mouse move and mouse pressed for the canvas, I can react to mouse moving and mouse button being pressed. However, there is no mouse move event as long as a button is pressed.

Suppose I wanted to implement a simple MS Paint style painting operation where the user presses a mouse button and drags the mouse over the canvas to draw. Would I try to do this with mouse move and mouse pressed events, or would this be a matter of `DragEvent`s?

I am asking because for some reason I thought `DragEvent` was for real drag and drop and not every operation that involved dragging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to draw a continuous line with mouse on JavaFX canvas?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43429251/230513)